# What event can I hook in to that fires as soons as my Gtk3 window *has already* closed?

Tags: gtk, gdk

I'm looking to execute some code just after my Gtk3 window closes.  I've tried `delete-event`, `destroy`, and `destroy-event` which seems to not fire at all.

I get that there's some difference between Gdk and Gtk, but I'm not exactly sure about what that is.  I assume I'm asking about the right thing.

I'm creating the window with the node.js binding of `gtk_window_new()`, and closing it with `gtk_window_close()`.  When doing that, and using the events mentioned above, the event handlers fire while the window is still on the screen.

edit:

As requested, some example code:

```
const gi = require('node-gtk')
const Gtk = gi.require('Gtk', '3.0');

gi.startLoop();
Gtk.init();

const win = new Gtk.Window();
win.on('destroy', () => Gtk.mainQuit());
win.on('delete-event', () => false);

const button = new Gtk.Button({ label: 'Do it' });
win.add(button);
button.on('clicked', function () {win.close();});

win.showAll();
Gtk.main();

shell_command("wmctrl -lG");

function shell_command(cmd_str) {

    const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
    code = execSync(cmd_str);
    return code.toString();

}
```

On my Linux Mint 19.3 system, the above code creates a small window with 1 button.  Clicking the button crashes execution with the following terminal error:

```
Error: Command failed: wmctrl -lG
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  20 (X_GetProperty)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x6c00003
  Serial number of failed request:  26
  Current serial number in output stream:  26
```

The window id `0x6c00003` is the window id of the window created by the above code, as proven by running wmctrl after running the script, but before pressing the button.

If I simply put the the call to `wmctrl` in a 50ms timer, it works without error.

```
setTimeout(function () {shell_command("wmctrl -lG");}, 50);
```

This is what leads me to believe it's a race condition.  I think `wmctrl` is getting window ids when my window still exists, but then further querying against those ids *after* my window has closed, and it causes the above error.  That's my theory, and if it's correct, `Gtk.main()` returns before the window is truly gone (and the same is true of the other events mentioned).

Comment: generally, these signals delete-event, destroy and destroy-event work. Could you share a sample code maybe with that we could understand why it's not working.

Comment: It's not that they don't work at all, it's that the window is still on screen while they are working.  `destroy-event` seems to not actually work though, but that may have something to do with the need to enable it at creation time, which I haven't done, and don't know how to do.

Sharing code is hard, because this is part of a broader application, and because I'm using a node module which most people aren't familiar with.  However, I'll try to edit some in.

Comment: @SivaGuru code is added.

Comment: upon getting the destruction signal try calling a function that free's all reference to the main window (gtk_widget_destroy or g_object_unref or ) and then try calling Gtk.mainQuit().  I tried modifying the c code but it works over there. Your reasoning to call it a reace condition seems the be valid(this issue could also be related to node-gtk).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

gboolean destroy(gpointer window, gpointer testing);

void destroy1(GtkWidget *window, gpointer testing);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  gtk_widget_add_events(GTK_WIDGET(window), GDK_ALL_EVENTS_MASK);

  gtk_widget_show(window);

  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy1), NULL);
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy-event", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);

  gtk_main();

  printf("closing application \n");
  // you could try to add the code here 
  //which will be only be exited after the window is destroyed
  sleep(10);
  return 0;
}

void destroy1(GtkWidget *window, gpointer testing) {
  printf("sleeping for 5 seconds \n");
  gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(window));
  sleep(5);
  gtk_main_quit();
  printf("i have slept \n");
}

gboolean destroy(gpointer window, gpointer testing) {
  printf("sleeping for 5 seconds \n");
  sleep(5);
  printf("i have slept \n");

  return TRUE;
  }
```

After the window is destroyed completely the main loop will end. so, you could try adding you code after gtk_main();

The ::destroy-event signal is emitted when a gdk-window is destroyed. You rarely get this signal, because most widgets disconnect themselves from their window before they destroy it, so no widget owns the window at destroy time.
(https://www.gnu.org/software/guile-gnome/docs/gtk/html/GtkWidget.html).

Comment: I can't believe what a moron I've been.  Obviously just putting it after `main()` was the thing to do.

Comment: This turned out not to do the trick.  Instead it caused what appears to be a race condition in `wmctrl`.  Essentially what happens is `Gtk.main()` returns after `win.close()`, then my code calls `wmctrl` which runs *while* Gtk *actually* closes the window, which causes `wmctrl` to throw an error.   `Gtk.main()` does not end synchronously.

Comment: i am not understanding this issue. could you just update your code with wmctrl like any sample working code would be nice..

Comment: I've further updated the code and expanded the explanation in the original post.  I've since changed my application in a way that makes this no longer matter, but  future searches may care.